# Laravel Joining 5 Tables using WhereNotIn

Tags: php, laravel, join, nested, subquery

I have 5 tables:

1. orders
2. order_subcontractor
3. Subcontractors
4. categories
5. category_subcontractor

Obviously, category_subcontractor and order_subcontractor are the pivot tables and a category has many orders.

So I would like retrieve Subcontractors from a Category which are not in an specific Order using orderID and CategoryID.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6tXj.png)

I used the following query, but empty data is returned.

```
$subcontractors = Subcontractor::join('category_subcontractor', 'subcontractors.id', '=', 'category_subcontractor.subcontractor_id')
        ->join('Categories', 'category_subcontractor.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->join('orders', 'categories.id', '=', 'orders.category_id')
        ->where('categories.id', '=', $catID)
        ->where('orders.id', '=', $orderID)
         ->whereNotIn('category_id',function($query){
            $query->select('orders.category_id')->from('orders');
         }) 
        ->orderBy('subcontractors.created_at', 'desc')
        ->get(['subcontractors.id as value', 'subcontractor_name as name']);
```

[ER-Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6tXj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured it out how to fetch the exact data. It could be inefficient because I fetch the demanded data in three queries however, it works.

Here is what I have done:

First I fetched all the subcontractors which are belongs to a category by joining the following 3 tables:

1. categories
2. category_subcontractor
3. subcontractor

   ```
   $q1 = Subcontractor::join('category_subcontractor', 'subcontractors.id', '=', 'category_subcontractor.subcontractor_id')
           ->join('Categories', 'category_subcontractor.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
           ->where('categories.id', '=', $catID)
           ->pluck('subcontractors.id as value')
           ->toArray();
   ```

Second, I fetched all the subcontractors which are added to an order by doing the following tables:

1. subcontractors
2. order_subcontractors
3. orders

   ```
   $q2 = Subcontractor::join('subcontractor_orders', 'subcontractors.id', '=', 'subcontractor_orders.subcontractor_id')
           ->join('orders', 'subcontractor_orders.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
           ->where('orders.id', '=', $orderID)
           ->where('orders.category_id', '=', $catID)
           ->pluck('subcontractors.id as value')
           ->toArray();
   ```

Lastly, I got the difference between $q1 and $q2 and query from the subcontractor table again using the last query result as follow:

```
$differenceArray = array_diff($q1, $q2);

 $subcontractors =  Subcontractor::whereIn('id', $differenceArray)
            ->get(['subcontractors.id as value', 'subcontractors.subcontractor_name as name']);
```